# How do I convert this CSV to a better format using PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, csv, formatting

I have a CSV file sorted by Country, then State, and then City. It looks like this:

```
USA,California,Arcata
USA,California,Bakersfield
USA,California,Barstow
USA,California,Berkeley
USA,California,Chico
USA,California,Delano
USA,California,El Centro
USA,California,Eureka
USA,California,Fresno
USA,California,Irvine
USA,Colorado,Colorado Springs
USA,Colorado,Denver
USA,Colorado,Durango
USA,Colorado,Fort Collins
```

I want to create an output file that looks like this:

```
USA
-California
--Bakersfield
--Barstow
--Berkeley
--Chico
--Delano
--El Centro
--Eureka
--Fresno
--Irvine
-Colorado
--Colorado Springs
--Denver
--Durango
--Fort Collins
```

I would like the states to be prepended with a single dash, and cities to be prepended with 2 dashes within each state.

I'm using PHP on WordPress. Can someone help me create this output? Thanks!

Comment: In what programming language and what have you tried so far?

Comment: show us what you have so far ...

Comment: What is technology in which you want the solution? Do you want PowerShell script or C# code or java code etc.?

Comment: Open your favorite text editor on whatever operating system you're using. Start writing code in your favorite programming language that will convert the text from your first example to the format in your second example. There - I've answered your question with the same amount of specificity you've used when writing your question. Now [edit] your question and make it more specific. What programming language are you using? What have you done so far to solve this yourself? Where is the code you've written, and what specific problems are you having with it? We're not a code writing service.

Comment: Use (or implement) associative arrays and then convert the result.

Comment: I'm not an experienced coder, but Mike's last comment gave me a starting point. I can write code within reason in PHP.

Comment: @Mayur Please check my answer in PowerShell. You can reuse the logic and implement similar thing to get your desired result in any Programming language. The **algorithm** would remain similar irrespective of the language you use.

Comment: A more complete description for how I added the data to Wordpress: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/creating-country-state-city-taxonomy-for-custom-post-type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the below script in **PowerShell**. I have made an assumption that there will be only one country. The entries can be jumbled in any way.

Also, I assume that there is this below row as the first row in your CSV for the headers:

```
Country,State,City
```

You can use similar logic in any other Programming language as well.

```
$csvInput = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Data\Test\abc.csv" | Sort-Object State

$outputFileContent = @()

$outputFileContent += ($csvInput[0].Country)

$oldState = ""
$newState = ""
foreach($csvRow in $csvInput)
{
    $newState = $csvRow.State
    if($newState -ne $oldState)
    {
        $outputFileContent+= ( "-" + $csvRow.State)
    }
    $oldState = $newState

    $outputFileContent += ("--" + $csvRow.City)
}

$outputFileContent | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Data\Test\testOutput.txt"
```

Replace "C:\Data\Test\abc.csv" with your input CSV file and "C:\Data\Test\testOutput.txt" with the path to your output file.

Comment: Thank you Aman!  That's awesome! There is actually going to be multiple countries, but I get what you are doing here:  
  
1. Open the CSV file  
2. Inspect each row  
3. See if the country/state was same as previous  
4. Output the city

Answer (score 0):

So I got it working, thanks to Aman, and Ken for the tips and showing me a starting point. It's not particularly elegant code, but it does work perfectly.

For anyone curious, copy/pasta the code below into yourfile.php, create the CSV file as I have formatted above and save as list.csv, put both files onto your PHP server, and execute yourfile.php in the browser, and it will output the results as intended.

```php
$myfile = fopen("list.csv", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");

//echo fread($myfile,filesize("list.csv"));

fclose($myfile);

$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('list.csv'));

//echo is_array($csv) ? 'Array' : 'not an Array';

//$line=1; //If you need to compare the array with your CSV to make sure all lines are included

foreach ($csv as $i => $row)
{
    $lastcountry=$country;
    $laststate=$state;

    $country="";
    $state="";
    $city="";

    $country=trim($row[0]);
    $state=trim($row[1]);
    $city=trim($row[2]);

    if ($country <> $lastcountry) {
        echo $country . "<br>";
    }
    if ($state <> $laststate) {
        echo "-" . $state . "<br>";
    }
    echo "--" . $city . "<br>";

    //$line++;
    //echo $line . " <strong>Country:</strong> " . $country;
    //echo " <strong>State: </strong> " . $state;
    //echo " <strong>City: </strong>" . $city . "<br>";
}
```